# Word 2007. Different cameras creating different size pictures as inserted images

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2007

I take pictures with 4 or more different cameras. I batch re-size all images (using Pix-resizer) to 800x600 (or 600x800 for portrait). I use these in a Word document (using Word 2007, saving as .htm) which I then put up on my website. However, the same size pictures from the different cameras show different sizes in the document. Also when I save the document, Word saves multiple copies of each image in the images folder. This is particularly annoying as it wastes valuable space on the web server. (I've tried removing the ones that appear to be the wrong size, but then the images don't come up on the website).

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing that tells Word that if I drop a 800x600 image in, that's the size I want it to be?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word is oriented around paper, not webpages, so it is reading the DPI value stored in the image and using that to scale the pixel count into a physical size (in inches). For consistency, the easiest thing to do would be to adjust the DPI values to be the same during your resize operation.